# Branch my own repo in a separate folder - GitHub for Windows

Tags: branch, directory, github-for-windows

I need to work on different branches of a project at the same time, so having multiple folders (one for each branch) would be the faster and easier solution.

The problem arises when cloning my own repo: GitHub for Windows will recognize it and automatically move it to the main repository, where i can manage only one branch at a time.

I'm new to GitHub and couldn't find any working solution/workaround for version 1.2.110

Already tried, didn't work:

- [Github: how to checkout my own repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989893/github-how-to-checkout-my-own-repository)
- [Clone Github repo to specific Windows folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967353/clone-github-repo-to-specific-windows-folder)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7803102/1193335
- http://bitdrift.com/post/4534738938/fork-your-own-project-on-github

Comment: UPDATE: This is now easily done, by specifying different "local path" as clone each repo branch. HOWEVER it is still a PITA to manage, as the two repositories are listed by their remote repo name, which is of course identical, since they are branches of the same repo. TO KNOW WHICH PATH YOU ARE ON: In the list of local repos, hover mouse over one of them - will show the local path in tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

1 **Create a new folder**, eg: C:\GitHub\mynewbranch

2 **Drag it into GitHub**, fill the description fields, **uncheck** "Push to GitHub" and continue.

3 Open your "**Repository settings**":

[image: Repository settings]

And **fill the** "Primary remote (origin)" **field** with your repository url:

[image: Primary remote (origin) field]

4 Click "**Open in Git Shell**" (below "Repository settings") and **type this** in the command line:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<username>/<repository name>.git
```

5 **Then this**:

```
git pull origin <branch name>
```

6 **Switch** to the desired branch in GitHub, enjoy :-)

---

P.S. to **update** future changes from the master:

```
git pull origin master
```

Comment: Step 2 Drag it into GitHub - is this equivalent to creating a new local repository in that folder?